# inject headers to outcomming request from flask application

Tags: python-3.x, flask, header, middleware

I wanna know if there is way to inject headers to outcomming request from flask application.

I mean, I have a flask application that performs requests to other microservices in several parts on the business logic of the app using the requests library. I want to add some headers (like an ID) to all these requests in a centralized way, using a middleware or something similar?

Is this possible?